# user.save won't run the callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, server, sequelize.js

I'm trying to save information to my user schema in my database. I'm doing this using "user.save" but for some reason the code within the parenthesis is not run.

```
user.save(function(err) {
                    //THIS CODE DOESNT SEEM TO RUN 
                  if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                  } else {
                    res.json({ message: 'given a reset-token' })
                  }
                  //
                });
```

So I switched to the following code since I needed to get a success message from the server:

```
  user.save((err) => {
            console.log('hello');
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              console.log('err2');
              res.status(404).json({ message: 'Save error' });
            }
          }).then(() => {
            res.status(201).json({ message: 'Activated' });
          });
```

Witch successfully sends me the status code when changes to the user have been pushed to the database. Could anyone explain why the second one works and the first one doesn't? And if there is a better way to write this code?